# Read/write big integers or floats with a simple byte protocol in C

Tags: c, erlang, byte, stdin

*Disclaimer: The author of the question has an average knowledge of Erlang and a basic (but increasing) knowledge of C.*

I am using the `read()` function to read the bytes which my `port.c` program gets from the Erlang port example provided in the [Interoperability Tutorial User Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/users_guide.html) (it is also described in Chapter 12 of the "Erlang Programming" book).

But I tend to think that the question is not Erlang-related at all, because the wrong values that I get (e.g. 231 instead of 999) come from the C side.

The problem is that this protocol does not work with parameters which are more than 255 (otherwise it works nice). I guess it has something to do with the `byte` type and with `read_exact()` implementation, but I do not know how to fix it or make it possible to pass `float` values in it.

I have read a half of the K&R book in order to understand this code, but I am still stuck.

Here is the code:

Actual C functions:

```
/* complex.c */

int foo(int x) {
  return x+1;
}

int bar(int y) {
  return y*2;
}
```

C port:

/* port.c */

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

int main() {
  int fn, arg, res;
  byte buf[100];

  while (read_cmd(buf) > 0) {
    fn = buf[0];
    arg = buf[1];

    if (fn == 1) {
      res = foo(arg);
    } else if (fn == 2) {
      res = bar(arg);
    }

    buf[0] = res;
    write_cmd(buf, 1);
  }
}
```

Buffer management:

```
/* erl_comm.c */

typedef unsigned char byte;

read_cmd(byte *buf)
{
  int len;

  if (read_exact(buf, 2) != 2)
    return(-1);
  len = (buf[0] << 8) | buf[1];
  return read_exact(buf, len);
}

write_cmd(byte *buf, int len)
{
  byte li;

  li = (len >> 8) & 0xff;
  write_exact(&li, 1);

  li = len & 0xff;
  write_exact(&li, 1);

  return write_exact(buf, len);
}

read_exact(byte *buf, int len)
{
  int i, got=0;

  do {
    if ((i = read(0, buf+got, len-got)) <= 0)
      return(i);
    got += i;
  } while (got<len);

  return(len);
}

write_exact(byte *buf, int len)
{
  int i, wrote = 0;

  do {
    if ((i = write(1, buf+wrote, len-wrote)) <= 0)
      return (i);
    wrote += i;
  } while (wrote<len);

  return (len);
}
```

Erlang port:

```
-module(complex1).
-export([start/1, stop/0, init/1]).
-export([foo/1, bar/1]).

start(ExtPrg) ->
    spawn(?MODULE, init, [ExtPrg]).
stop() ->
    complex ! stop.

foo(X) ->
    call_port({foo, X}).
bar(Y) ->
    call_port({bar, Y}).

call_port(Msg) ->
    complex ! {call, self(), Msg},
    receive
    {complex, Result} ->
        Result
    end.

init(ExtPrg) ->
    register(complex, self()),
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    Port = open_port({spawn, ExtPrg}, [{packet, 2}]),
    loop(Port).

loop(Port) ->
    receive
    {call, Caller, Msg} ->
        Port ! {self(), {command, encode(Msg)}},
        receive
        {Port, {data, Data}} ->
            Caller ! {complex, decode(Data)}
        end,
        loop(Port);
    stop ->
        Port ! {self(), close},
        receive
        {Port, closed} ->
            exit(normal)
        end;
    {'EXIT', Port, Reason} ->
        exit(port_terminated)
    end.

encode({foo, X}) -> [1, X];
encode({bar, Y}) -> [2, Y].

decode([Int]) -> Int.
```

I have made a silly attempt to change

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

to

```
typedef int byte;
```

but it did not work.

Actually, there are two problems:

- if we call the port with a parameter, which is bigger than 255 (e.g. `foo(256)` from the Erlang port) , the execution will terminate at read() inside read_cmd() with i = 0;
- if we call the port with a parameter which is less than 255, but the result of the function is more than 255 (say `int foo(int x) { return x+1000; }`, then the program does not terminate, but we get some unexpected value to our Erlang port;

So, the question is: what should I do in order to make the protocol work with bigger numbers or even with floats?

Answer (score 2):

Bytes on any machine you're ever likely to encounter can only hold values from -128 to 127 (signed) or 0 to 255 (unsigned); anything else requires marshaling data between the two.  http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.6/pdf/tutorial.pdf is the official Erlang tutorial for marshaling data between Erlang and other languages, and includes examples in C.

Comment: Yes, I know that unsigned bytes are 0 to 255. The link that you have provided seems to be the PDF version of the tutorial that I referred to in my question.

Comment: So, if you read it, and you understand the range of a byte, why were you expecting values outside the range of a byte to work?

Comment: I did not expect these values to work outside the range of a byte. I know that the example works nice, but I want to tweak it. The question was "what should I do in order to make the protocol work with bigger numbers or even with floats?". Sorry if I did not make it clear enough.

Comment: in this case, just read the next section (1.5) of the pdf, which describes how to use Erl_Interface in C (unless you want to invent you own marshalling scheme of course) edit: you find the same chapter in the homepage you link, of course: http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/erl_interface.html

Answer (score 2):

An example of marshalling `byte`s into larger constructs is already present in `read_cmd`.

```
...
  int len;

  if (read_exact(buf, 2) != 2)
    return(-1);
  len = (buf[0] << 8) | buf[1];
...
```

That takes the first two `byte`s out of `buf` and treats them as an `int` (a four-`byte` structure). According to [this](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/CONCEPT/data_types.html#double), a `double` is 8 bytes, so in theory, you should be able to apply that same approach. You'd want to do something like (untested, almost guaranteed not to work, for illustrative purposes only, etc.):

```
double marshall_eight(byte *buff) {
  int i;
  double tmp, res;
  for(i=0; i<8;i++) {
    tmp = buff[i] << 8*i;
    res += tmp;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the conversion from Erlang is to a byte array and not a character array.

Code is a bit loose, simplest answer ...

```
while (read_cmd(buf) > 0) { 
 fn = buf[0];
    arg = buf[1];
```

should have been:

```
while (arg=read_cmd(buf) > 0) {
 fn = buf[0];
```

Your code will only handle bytes and ints, it cannot handle floats and doubles.

There are additional errors in your write cmds.

------------Edit-----------------
Here's an example of what you are trying to achieve in c:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

 /*
  * With certain compilers  __attribute__((transparent_union)) 
  * can be used to ease handling of an unknown type.
  */
 union  u_unionalue
 {
     char                char_union;
     unsigned char       u_char_union;
     short               s_int_union;
     unsigned short      us_int_union;
     int                 int_union;
     unsigned int        u_int_union;
     long                l_int_union;
     unsigned long       ul_int_union;
     long long           ll_int_union;
     unsigned long long  ull_int_union;
     float               float_union;
     double              double_union;
     long double         l_double_union;
 };

 enum e_type
 {
     char_enum    ,
     u_char_enum  ,
     s_int_enum   ,
     us_int_enum  ,
     int_enum     ,
     u_int_enum   ,
     l_int_enum   ,
     ul_int_enum  ,
     ll_int_enum  ,
     ull_int_enum ,
     float_enum   ,
     double_enum  ,
     l_double_enum,
     last_type
 };

 struct s_type
 {
     int  type;
     char *name;
     union u_unionalue value;
     int   size;
     char *stringFormat;

 } as_typeList[]=
 /**
  * This is a quick example of how convoluted type handling can be in C. The 
  * non portable  __attribute__((transparent_union)) can be useful if the 
  * complier supports it. This helps to 
  * reduce the amount of casting, but these are the convoluted tricks that 
  * occur behind the scenes. C++ has to handle this in the compiler as well
  * as a result .. sometimes what you get is not what you expect.
  */
 {
     { char_enum    ,  "char"              ,  {.char_union=(1 << (-1 + sizeof( char ) * 8  ))}, sizeof( char ),"%+d" },
     { u_char_enum  ,  "unsigned char"     ,  {.u_char_union=-1} , sizeof( unsigned char ) ,"%+d" },
     { s_int_enum   ,  "short"             ,  {.s_int_union=((short)1 << (-1 + sizeof( short ) * 8))}  , sizeof( short ),"%+d" },
     { us_int_enum  ,  "unsigned short"    ,  {.us_int_union=-1}, sizeof( unsigned short ),"%+u"  },
     { int_enum     ,  "int"               ,  {.int_union = ((int)1<< (-1 + sizeof( int) * 8  ))}, sizeof( int), "%+i"  },
     { u_int_enum   ,  "unsigned int"      ,  {.u_int_union=-1}, sizeof( unsigned int ), "%+u"  },
     { l_int_enum   ,  "long"              ,  {.l_int_union=((long)1<< (-1 + sizeof( long) * 8  ))}, sizeof( long ), "%+li" },
     { ul_int_enum  ,  "unsigned long"     ,  {.ul_int_union=(long)-1}, sizeof( unsigned long ), "%+lu" },
     { ll_int_enum  ,  "long long"         ,  {.ll_int_union=(long long)-1 }, sizeof( long long ), "%+lli"},
     { ull_int_enum ,  "unsigned long long",  {.ull_int_union=((unsigned long long)1<< (-1 + sizeof( unsigned long long) * 8  ))}, sizeof( unsigned long long  ), "%+llu"},
     { float_enum   ,  "float"             ,  {.float_union=1e+37L}, sizeof( float ), "%+f"  },
     { double_enum  ,  "double"            ,  {.double_union=1e+37L}, sizeof( double ), "%+lf"  },
     { l_double_enum,  "long double"       ,  {.l_double_union=1e+37L}, sizeof( long double), "%+lle"}
 };


 /**
  * This is how your foo and bar functions should be organized this would 
  * allow handling for all your types. but the type is needed.
  */
 void sprintVal(struct s_type *typeVal, char*buf)
 {
     switch(typeVal->type)
     {
     case char_enum     :
         sprintf(buf, typeVal->stringFormat, typeVal->value.char_union);
         break;
     case u_char_enum   :
         sprintf(buf, typeVal->stringFormat, typeVal->value.u_char_union);
         break;
     case s_int_enum    :
         sprintf(buf, typeVal->stringFormat, typeVal->value.s_int_union);
         break;
     case us_int_enum   :
         sprintf(buf, typeVal->stringFormat, typeVal->value.us_int_union);
         break;
     case int_enum      :
         sprintf(buf, typeVal->stringFormat, typeVal->value.int_union);
         break;
     case u_int_enum    :
         sprintf(buf, typeVal->stringFormat, typeVal->value.u_int_union);
         break;
     case l_int_enum    :
         sprintf(buf, typeVal->stringFormat, typeVal->value.l_int_union);
         break;
     case ul_int_enum   :
         sprintf(buf, typeVal->stringFormat, typeVal->value.ul_int_union);
         break;
     case ll_int_enum   :
         sprintf(buf, typeVal->stringFormat, typeVal->value.ll_int_union);
         break;
     case ull_int_enum  :
         sprintf(buf, typeVal->stringFormat, typeVal->value.ull_int_union);
         break;
     case float_enum    :
         sprintf(buf, typeVal->stringFormat, typeVal->value.float_union);
         break;
     case double_enum   :
         sprintf(buf, typeVal->stringFormat, typeVal->value.double_union);
         break;
     case l_double_enum :
         sprintf(buf, typeVal->stringFormat, typeVal->value.l_double_union);
         break;
     }
 }


 void print_types()
 {
     int i=0;
     char buf[100];

     while(i < last_type )
     {
         sprintVal( &as_typeList[i], buf);
         printf( "Type: %-18s value=%-30s size=  %-dBytes \n", as_typeList[i].name, buf, as_typeList[i].size );
         i++;
     };
 }

 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {

     print_types();
     return(0);
 }
```

The biggest issue in your problem is the messaging you have between erlang and c. Your current format is /CMD/VALUE/ minimally this should be /CMD/TYPE/VALUE/, though a legnth of message header and a checksum footer is common. Types should be promoted so the larger result value can be returned. So knowing what you are passing is needed.

Oh, if you pass the data as a string, you can size your type appropriately to a certain degree. It also prevents endian issues if there's a difference between the ends of the pipe.